# Insert/Update set of records

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The stored Procedure below used to insert/ update the sql database

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdate]
@dp             char(32),
@dv             char(32),
@e_num          char(12),
@mail           varchar(50),
@emerg          char(32),
@opt1           char(16),
@stat           char(20),
@e_id           char(35),
@e_tit          varchar(64),
@e_date         datetime
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[sampleemployee] WHERE e_id= @e_id)
BEGIN
 UPDATE [dbo].[sampleemployee]
   SET  dp      = @dp,
        dv      = @dv,
        e_num   = @e_num,
        mail    = @mail,
        emerg   = @emerg,
        opt1    = @opt1,
        stat    = @stat,
        e_tit   = @e_tit,
        e_date  = @e_date
 WHERE  e_id    = @e_id
 END
 ELSE 
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[sampleemployee]( dp, dv, e_num, mail, emerg, opt1, stat, e_id, e_tit, e_date) 
 VALUES ( @dp, @dv, @e_num, @mail, @emerg, @opt1, @stat, @e_id, @e_tit, @e_date );
 END
 END;
```

But it just inserts one row.But, I have set of records from Oracle database which I have to insert/update depending on the e_id in to SQA database.Not sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: Of course it only does one insert. You are using scalar values here. Not quite sure what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Also don't say `IF EXISTS / UPDATE / ELSE / INSERT`. It is sufficient (and one less operation) to say `UPDATE / IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 / INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement looks good, but it seems that @e_id is not matching e_id. In cases like this, I write simpler statements for debugging purposes:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[sampleemployee] where e_id = 'some known value')
BEGIN
PRINT 'YES'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'NO'
END
```

Maybe this will help point out something you're overlooking. Is @e_id an exact match for e_id, or do you have some cleanup to do?